# Optimize runtime for finding nth prime number

Tags: java, optimization, runtime

This is a Java program that finds the nth prime number in a given range.
The max range that can be input is 1-1500000.
The code output is correct for all the possible test cases, but has to be optimized for runtime. **What optimization techniques can be applied in this code?**

```
import java.io.*;
class prime
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String m1,m2,m;
        int n1=0,n2=0,n=0;
        try
        {
//input as string instead of integer because errors must be displayed only after all the values have been input

        m1=br.readLine();   //range minimum value
        m2=br.readLine();   //range max value
        m=br.readLine();    //nth value in range
        n1=Integer.parseInt(m1);
        n2=Integer.parseInt(m2);
        n=Integer.parseInt(m);
        if(n1<0||n2>1500000||n1>n2||n==0)
                throw new Exception();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int k=n1,count=0,count1=0;
        while(k<=n2&&count1<=n)
        {
            count=0;
            for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
            {
                if(k%i==0)
                    count++;
            }
            if(count==2)
            {
                count1++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        if(count1==n)
        {
            System.out.println(k);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(count1<n)
        {
            System.out.println("No prime number is present at this index");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for divisors between 2 and square root of k. If you don't find any, you've found a prime.

```
    int k=n1,count1=0;
    while(k<=n2&&count1<=n)
    {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for(int i=2;i <= Math.sqrt(k) ;i++)
        {
            if(k%i==0) 
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
             count1++;
        k++;
    }
```

Also, you can handle 2 explicitly and skip every other even number.

Comment: 0 and 1 would be considered to be prime in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't test "has exactly 2 divisors", test "is not divisible by numbers other than 1 and itself".
2. Don't test all values <= k as divisors, test all values <= sqrt(k).

   (If a number is divisible by a number greater than sqrt(k), then the result of the division is also an divisor, but would have been found earlier)
3. Maybe reuse already calculated primes; You only need to test prime numbers as possible divisors. However you need to be careful. If you e.g. search in range 9999-9999, it doesn't make sense to calculate all the smaller primes, however if the range is 1-9999, it reduces the number of checks you have to make. You could combine both approaches and test numbers smaller than n1 the "normal" way and test all larger divisors using the primes you already found.

Your loop can be rewritten like this to apply 1. and 2.:

```
int k=Math.max(2, n1); // 0 and 1 are no prime
int count1 = 0;
while(k <= n2 && count1 <= n) {
    final int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(k);
    count1++; // asume it's a prime
    for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++) {
        if(k % i == 0) {
            // divisible by number other than 1 and itself -> not a prime
            count1--;
            break;
        }
    }
    k++;
}
```

This reduces the running time from `O((n2)² - (n1)²)` to

[image: O((n2)^1.5 - (n1)^1.5)]

Answer (score 0):

As your maximum value is limited, it makes sense to keep a table of the primes from 2 to 1229  (1229² = 1510441) and try them in turn until the number gets smaller than the square of the prime. 2 can be tested without a division. You can also store a table of the squares.

```
      2      3      5      7     11     13     17     19     23     29 
     31     37     41     43     47     53     59     61     67     71 
     73     79     83     89     97    101    103    107    109    113 
    127    131    137    139    149    151    157    163    167    173 
    179    181    191    193    197    199    211    223    227    229 
    233    239    241    251    257    263    269    271    277    281 
    283    293    307    311    313    317    331    337    347    349 
    353    359    367    373    379    383    389    397    401    409 
    419    421    431    433    439    443    449    457    461    463 
    467    479    487    491    499    503    509    521    523    541 
    547    557    563    569    571    577    587    593    599    601 
    607    613    617    619    631    641    643    647    653    659 
    661    673    677    683    691    701    709    719    727    733 
    739    743    751    757    761    769    773    787    797    809 
    811    821    823    827    829    839    853    857    859    863 
    877    881    883    887    907    911    919    929    937    941 
    947    953    967    971    977    983    991    997   1009   1013 
   1019   1021   1031   1033   1039   1049   1051   1061   1063   1069 
   1087   1091   1093   1097   1103   1109   1117   1123   1129   1151 
   1153   1163   1171   1181   1187   1193   1201   1213   1217   1223 
   1229
```